# Problem when defining an object in angular 11

Tags: angular

I am following a tutorial that was made using Angular 8 and I am having an issue when it comes to defining an object.

```
brews: Object;
```

Error - Property 'brews' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.ts(2564)

How would I do the equivilent in Angular 11 ?

Comment: Can you provide the code to your class file?

Comment: `brews!: Object`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the rule `strictPropertyInitialization` in tslint.json.

You can read more about this here [TypeScript complain "has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor" about constructors by returning constructed object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54104187/typescript-complain-has-no-initializer-and-is-not-definitely-assigned-in-the-co/54104796)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to fix this:

A. If you are using VSCode you need to change the TS version that the editor use.

B. Just initialize the array when you declare it inside the constructor.