# Page is not loading from the top when routing in angular?

Tags: angular, routes, angular-routing

My problem is -- Consider there are two pages A and B.
If I am on page A and scroll down the page and click some button to navigate to page B, the page B remains at the same scroll position that I have scrolled in page A. Instead of this I want the page B should load from the top no matter of how much I have scrolled on previous page.

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'', redirectTo:'home', pathMatch:'full'},
  {path:'home', component: HomeComponent},
  {path:'about', component: AboutComponent},
  {path:'product', component: ProductComponent},
  {path:'contact', component: ContactComponent}
];
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

How to resolve this problem ?

And also I tried some solution like :

*{scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled'}*

*(activate)="onActivate($event)*

*window.scrollTo(0,0)*

All these things I tried is scrolling all over the top(page B) from that scrolled position on previous page(page A). Any other solution for this or I am missing anything ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: In your component B HTML, wrap your page in `<main>`. Then, in your component B,

**component-b.ts**

```js
export class ComponentB implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('main') main: ElementRef;


  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.main.nativeElement.scrollTop = 0;
  }

}
```

This should scroll the page to the top after the page is loaded.

Comment: I tried your code but there is an error called "Property 'main' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor." @Nam Dao

Comment: Check this maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54104187/typescript-complain-has-no-initializer-and-is-not-definitely-assigned-in-the-co

Comment: The error that I mention above is cleared. But the solution you gave is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it, in the container `AppComponent`:

```js
        this.router.events.subscribe((evt) => {
          if (!(evt instanceof NavigationEnd)) {
            return;
          }
          let x = document.getElementsByClassName('mat-drawer-content');
          if (x.length > 0) x[0].scrollTo(0, 0);
        });
```

If you're using the `mat-drawer` from Angular material this will work. If you're using another div that scrolls replace it with that.

Comment: I am new to angular. Do I have to do this for every component that I have @favdev .

Comment: @Aasif not if you put it in your `AppComponent`'s `ngOnInit()`